# D3.js redraw chart after brushing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on a D3.js chart where I would like to brush on a timeline. I stucked when I want to redraw the chart with the new data.

```
´function brushed() {

  var startDate=new Date(brush.extent()[0]);
  var endDate=new Date(brush.extent()[1]);

  var newDates=[];

  var i=0;

 while(JSONdata.measurementPoints[i].measurementDateTime<=endDate){
   if(JSONdata.measurementPoints[i].measurementDateTime>=startDate){
    newDates.push(JSONdata.measurementPoints[i].measurementDateTime);
  }
   i++;
}
if(newDates.length>0){
   chart.select('path').attr('d',pathGenerator(newDates));
   chart.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
 }
}´
```

My problem is that after I change the data on the element the whole graph disappear. I am pretty rookie in D3.js and dont really know if this is the best way to achive this functionality.

I appreciate any suggestion.

Code: http://codepen.io/laczko090/pen/ozJANP?editors=1010

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i have seen this post in the morning also

Comment: that was a different question what I solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redraw the main graph line and axes in `brushed`.

[Modified CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwzbmX)

Save a reference to the graph line's path:

```
var path = series.append('path')
    .attr('vector-effect', 'non-scaling-stroke')
```

[...]

In `brushed`, redraw:

```
path.attr('d', pathGenerator(dates));

xAxis.scale(xScale);
xAxisEl.call(xAxis);
```

Comment: Wow, this is awesome. Thank you very much!